# Some Test Questions About iOS XCTest

Tags: ios, testing, xctest

1. how to test `viewController`, `viewdidload` & `viewdidAppear`, in test case it will never invoke. how to test my custom viewdidload code?
2. Are all test cases concurrent? or which test case will be invoke first in all test file. I want to fetch some data from network before all test case, how to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1. You can create UIAutomation bot for testing your code. If you don't want any integration tests, you can try calling directly following functions like `[viewController viewDidLoad]`

For 2. tests in one file are executed alphabetically, I saw a lot of people to do test like 001_testSomething, 002_testSomethingElse etc.

If you want to prepare your data you can do it in setUp function:

```
- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];
    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! answer For 2, i want fetch data before all test case in all test file .setUp function is only in one file

Comment: How about in your first test case create singleton and use it through other test cases? Usually people use mocks/stubs to test different things...